# VMWare Workstation processor configuration

Tags: memory, virtual-machine, cpu, vmware

I want to configure VMWare Workstation so that it is optimal and both host and guest Operating Systems run smoothly. Will anyone of you please help me in choosing right configuration. My laptop system configurations are:

Processor: Intel Core i3 (2.67Ghz)
Memory: 6GB
Graphic Card: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650 (1gb)
Hard Disk: 500 GB
Host OS: Windows 8.1 64bit (fully updated at the time of question)

Despite giving plenty of RAM to guest OS, Guest still runs slower. I am having problem in getting correct configuration of Processor cores also. In the following image:

[Image showing VMWare Processor configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLpdM.png)

What does it mean by

```
Number of Processors
```

and

```
Number of Processor Cores
```

Does it mean how many processor and cores i am assigning to Virtual Machine or does it only specifies how many cores and processor i have. Like i have Core i3 which is dual core and supports two additional virtual cores also. Like each core using hyper threading technology make another virtual core. So in total it becomes 4 cores.

What should i put here?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: What Apple computer do you have?

Comment: @Ramhound I have mentioned that i am using Windows 8.1 as Host. Mac OS X is the guest using VMWare Workstation.

Comment: The os x license specifically prohibits it from being ran on non-Apple hardware

Comment: I am on an experience as a student. Not a professional. So it is just for testing purpose.

Comment: Does not matter it's only for testing purposes; there are other communities that will guide you to hardware that supports os x which will lead to hardware that can also run virtual instances of os x this isn't that community due to the license

Comment: @Ramhound i have edited my question to be generalized for any virtual machine. Can you please answer it now.

Comment: You don't indicate how many cores you want your virtual machine to have access too; your machine only has one processor by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Number of Processors` means what the name indicates. This lets you configure how many processors you want to assign to the VM. `Number of Processor Cores` is also clear, this it allows you to select the number of CPU cores you want to assign to a VM.

For the i3 you should assign 1 CPU and 2 cores. The Intel i3 has 2 core with 2 Hyper Threading cores. So the Host has still room to operate fine.

The different settings is available [because not all Operating systems can handle many CPUs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor#Licensing). The home Editions of Windows can use only 1 CPU but many CPU cores and only the Enterprise/Pro Version can run 2 CPUs.

Comment: What should be optimal processor and ram configuration on Core i3 2.67 GHz and 6gb RAM? Please help me regarding this.

Comment: assign 1 CPU and 2 cores

Comment: If I assign 1 CPU and two cores then what is left for host operative system? Doesn't this mean that I am assigning complete i3 CPU to VM?

Comment: the i3 has 2 core with 2 Hyper Threading cores. So the Host has still room to operate fine.

Comment: Great. It cleared processor configuration problem.

Comment: Please suggest about RAM also. How much RAM out of 6gb to VM?

Comment: this depends on which Guest OS you want to run.